# Angular: Passing values back to service

Tags: javascript, angular

As **customparameters: CustomParameter[]** I pushed values from my ng-service via my ng-component to the html view. There I want to change the values:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let customparameter of customparameters">
    <label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="customparameter.wert" />
    </label>
  </li>
  <p>
    <button (click)="save(customparameters)">Speichern</button>
  </p>
</ul>
```

How do I pass the changed values now back to my ng-service?

This wasn't working:

ng-component:

```
//...
customparameters: CustomParameter[];
//...
save(customparameters: CustomParameter[]) {
    this.customParameterService.setCustomParameters(this.customparameters);
  }
//...
```

ng-service

```
//...
customparameters: CustomParameter[];
//...
setCustomParameters(customparameters) {
    console.log(this.customparameters); //still undefined
    console.log(this.customparameters.length); //should be 5 but undefined
}
//...
```

The log shows

> TypeError: this.customparameters is undefined

Does anyone have a short best practice for me? Thanks!

Comment: why do you use `this.customparameters`? you have got `customparameters` as parameters. use them as just `customparameters`

Comment: Is this modern Angular or the original one? If it's the original one, you should use the angularjs tag instead.

I don't know angularjs, but in a nutshell I think your problem is you aren't injecting the service as a dependency into your component. Any basic guide on angular should show you how to do that.

Comment: could you please provide either a JS Fiddle or a repository with the non working code? It would be especially benefitial to know what is the initial value of the customParameters variable. Also you should either add customParameters as a parameter of the save function or use this.customParameters, but not both.

Comment: Just removing the "this". Too easy. Thanks! I am using Angular 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove all "this" should work. "this.customparameters" was referring to the customparameters you declared inside the component, which was never be set so it is undefined

```
save(customparameters: CustomParameter[]) {
    this.customParameterService.setCustomParameters(customparameters);
  }

setCustomParameters(customparameters) {
    console.log(customparameters); 
    console.log(customparameters.length); 
}
```